# How to log SQL queries on a Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL 11 instance?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have to log all DDL and DML queries executed on a Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance.

I checked a lot of websites, but there is no clear information available. I tried using the `pgAudit` extension, but that is not supported by Cloud SQL.

Can someone please suggest the extension to be used or any other way of logging SQL queries?
Also, if the user logins can be logged, then that will be helpful, too.

Comment: `PgAudit` is now in preview for CloudSql -https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/pg-audit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short Answer - **Database Flags**

The solution provided in the other answer can be used, if PostgreSQL is locally installed or if we have access to the server container. In Google Cloud, however, this file cannot be directly accessed from the instance.

I found that this can be achieved on Google Cloud SQL instance by setting the various parameters given in this link - [PostgreSQL configuration parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-logging.html) as database flags.

**Note:** All of the parameters are not supported, hence verify in the official documentation by Google given below.

[Google Cloud Database Flags for PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags)

Comment: Awesome! just what I needed after wasting one day trying to figure out. Wonder how you found out.

Can we restrict few db/ user so that their actions are not logged for instance cloudSqlAdmin.

Comment: @bak2trak, You can add a filter in Logs viewer in GCP assuming that you would redirect these logs to a GCP bucket. There's a filter query at the top which you can use to exclude specific users from showing up. This is just for viewing. All queries will be logged anyway based on your preference

Answer (score 1):

Add in `postgresql.conf`:

```
log_statement=mod
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-logging.html says

> logs all ddl statements, plus data-modifying statements such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, and COPY FROM. PREPARE, EXECUTE, and
>   EXPLAIN ANALYZE statements are also logged if their contained command
>   is of an appropriate type.

To log connections and disconnections, add in `postgresql.conf`:

```
log_connections=on
log_disconnections=on
```

Answer (score 1):

On October 12, 2020 Google Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL added support for pgAudit.  Please check these [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/pg-audit) for more information.